# jQuery Map Realtime Data Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, web-scraping, real-time

I've created [this map](http://jordanhuxley.com/projects/test-match-runs-map/index.html) based on [this data](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=runs;size=200;template=results;type=team), which is updated as and when the statistics change.

At present the data used in the interactive map I've created is static, and thus out of date when the statistics change.

I would like to create a realtime map of this data, however, I'm unsure as to how this can be achieved. The interactive map uses the Mapael jQuery plugin. I've checked the documentation and it doesn't provide any guidelines as to how this can be achieved.

The ESPN API doesn't provide the data needed for this realtime map. I have an API to the data using import.io. Details on the import.io JavaScript integration can be found on their website.

Ideally, it would be very helpful if someone could provide an example for one of the variables and then I will be able to complete the code for the rest.

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated!

Comment: I would prefer not to use the ESPN API.

Import.io appears to offer an alternative solution, however, I don't have the technical proficiency to implement it, especially with this jQuery map plugin.

Comment: I don't think I follow the question. Your map is based on the data in your second link, but the map is just using static data at the moment. You are scraping the data locally using import.io and uploading that to your cloud - are you accessing the data from the remote import.io API on your map? If you are using an API anyway, would it not be best to just use the ESPN one (per your comment)? Or does that not offer the data your want (per your question)?

Answer (score 0):

If you chose the Json format for your API, you can use the jQuery getJSON callback function to implement the latest information your map built in your HTML,  target exactly the variables like "India" or "236,385" and change them to your latest data coming from JSON API.

**http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/**

Comment: Yes, I have an API for the data from import.io. http://import.io/data/integrate/#js